# Do a Thevenin source and its equivalent Norton source always supply equal power?

Tags: power-supply, power, thevenin, norton

Power supplied by a Thevenin source

$$P_{Thevenin} = V_{Th}^2 \frac{1}{R_{Th}+R_L}$$

Power supplied by its equivalent Norton source

$$\begin{eqnarray}
P_{Norton} & = & I_N^2 \frac{R_{Th} R_L}{R_{Th}+R_L} \\
 & = & \left(\frac{V_{Th}}{R_{Th}}\right)^2 \frac{R_{Th} R_L}{R_{Th}+R_L} \\
 & = & V_{Th}^2 \frac{R_L/R_{Th}}{R_{Th}+R_L}
\end{eqnarray}$$

So power supplied by a Thevenin Source and its equivalent Norton source are equal only when \$R_{Th} = R_L\$.

Is it true or am I missing something?

Comment: The power consumed by the internal resistor/conductor should not be considered part of the power "supplied" by the source.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're missing something.

The Thévenin source includes both the voltage source AND the resistor, and the Norton source includes both the current source and the resistor.

In both cases, the power consumed by the internal resistor is not considered to be power "delivered" by the source. Instead, consider only the source's terminal voltage (where it connects to the load) and the current passing from the source to the load.

You'll find that they are exactly equivalent, regardless of the load. This is the whole point of having "equivalent" sources in the first place. You can replace any real source with its Thévenin or Norton equivalent and get identical system behavior. If each replacement source is exactly equivalent to the original, it follows that they must also be equivalent to each other.

Comment: So last time I calculated the power generated by the voltage source in Thevenin and the power generated by the voltage source maintaining  a constant iNorton. Apparently, although they are "delivering" equal power to the load but are generating different amounts of power.

Comment: Yes, their internal efficiency is different, but that's a different question altogether.

Comment: The internal efficiency of the Thevenin and Norton circuits aren't equal, **and** neither one is likely to match the internal efficiency of whatever real source your Thevenin/Norton circuit is modeling.

Comment: Clearly different cases because the Norton model will dissipate power with no load connected (current flows through \$\small R_{N}=\small R_{TH}\$); the Thevenin model will not (source and \$\small R_{TH}\$ are in series, hence open circuit).

Comment: @Chu: ... and exactly the opposite when the terminals are shorted.